# Find out if AVAudioPlayer finished playing inside a function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

How can you find out if a AVAudioPlayer finished playing a sound *inside of a function*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you really mean "via a function" because you should be able to use the obj-c bracket syntax `[myAudioPlayer isPlaying]` from inside your function.

If my assumption is correct, it may be worthwhile to read [this](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/02/nil-and-nil.html) and [this](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html).  Then the following will make sense:

`objc_msgSend(myAudioPlayer,@selector(isPlaying:));`

Comment: How can you put that in a "if"-statement?

Comment: You should NEVER call `objc_msgSend` directly.